# iphone 2 buttons in nav bar

Tags: iphone, button, navbar

I have a nav bar (with navigation), I have included 2 buttons to the nav bar, but if I allocate one of the buttons to left, my navigation button dissapears (doughh),
so how can I have, my navigation button, and 2 more buttons?
here the code I use:

from viewDidLoad

```
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 30);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
[infoButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal]; [img release];
//[infoButton setTitle:@"xuxu"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *modalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:modalButton animated:YES];
[modalButton release];


UIButton* iButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
iButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 30);
UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
[iButton setImage:imag forState:UIControlStateNormal]; [imag release];
//[infoButton setTitle:@"xuxu"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *modalButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:iButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:modalButton2 animated:YES];
[modalButton2 release];
```

so my second button is set to

> setLeftBarButtonItem

is there anything like setCenter?? or a way to set the position with x,y??
I need the 2 buttons keeping my button on the left for navigation purposes (3 buttons)

thank you!

Comment: You need three buttons 2 on left and 1 on right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for understanding how you can add two or more button on nav bar

```
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 30);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
    [infoButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal]; [img release];
    [infoButton setTitle:@"xuxu"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *modalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:modalButton animated:YES];
    [modalButton release];


    UIButton* iButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 30);
    iButton.frame = CGRectMake(42, 10, 40, 30);
    UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"];
    [iButton setImage:imag forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
     [aButton setImage:imag forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [imag release];
    [infoButton setTitle:@"xuxu"forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [iButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIView *viewForAdd=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)];
    [viewForAdd addSubview:iButton];
    [viewForAdd addSubview:aButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *modalButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:viewForAdd];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:modalButton2 animated:YES];
    [modalButton2 release];
```

Comment: great thank you just what I needed, to be able to set the x position, cheers